# Стейты реакт в методах

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я могу создать стейт и менять его в классе так:

```
state = {
  test: '',
}

this.setState({test: 'test'})
```

Как засунуть такие стейты в метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В реакт методах есть хуки, пример useState;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

// state = переменная стейта

// setState = функция которая меняет эту переменную

// initialState = дефолтное значение этой переменной
```

Документация [тап](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Comment: замечу что хуки доступны с версии react >= 16.8

Comment: Спасибо) Все вышло, версия подходит